# Mathematica Downvalue Lhs

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Does anybody know if there is a built-in function in Mathematica for getting the lhs of downvalue rules (without any holding)?  I know how to write the code to do it, but it seems basic enough for a built-in

For example:

```
a[1]=2;
a[2]=3;
```

`BuiltInIDoNotKnowOf[a]` returns `{1,2}`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This seems to work; not sure how useful it is, though:

```
a[1] = 2
a[2] = 3
a[3] = 5
a[6] = 8
Part[DownValues[a], All, 1, 1, 1]
```

Comment: Yeah, I tried to do something similar with [[]] notation, but it turned off the hold and I'd get the rhs.  But, this works great!

Comment: Looks like DownValues[a][[All, 1, 1, 1]] works too, at least in this simple example.

Answer (score 22):

This is like `keys()` in Perl and Python and other languages that have built in support for hashes (aka dictionaries).  As your example illustrates, Mathematica supports hashes without any special syntax.  Just say `a[1] = 2` and you have a hash. [1]
To get the keys of a hash, I recommend adding this to your init.m or your personal utilities library:

```
keys[f_] := DownValues[f][[All,1,1,1]]  (* Keys of a hash/dictionary. *)
```

(Or the following pure function version is supposedly slightly faster:

```
keys = DownValues[#][[All,1,1,1]]&;     (* Keys of a hash/dictionary. *)
```

)

Either way, `keys[a]` now returns what you want.  (You can get the values of the hash with `a /@ keys[a]`.)  If you want to allow for higher arity hashes, like `a[1,2]=5; a[3,4]=6` then you can use this:

```
SetAttributes[removeHead, {HoldAll}];
removeHead[h_[args___]] := {args}
keys[f_] := removeHead @@@ DownValues[f][[All,1]]
```

Which returns `{{1,2}, {3,4}}`.  (In that case you can get the hash values with `a @@@ keys[a]`.)

Note that `DownValues` by default sorts the keys, which is probably not a good idea since at best it takes extra time. If you want the keys sorted you can just do `Sort@keys[f]`.  So I would actually recommend this version:

```
keys = DownValues[#,Sort->False][[All,1,1,1]]&;
```

Interestingly, there is no mention of the `Sort` option in the `DownValues` documention.  I found out about it from an old post from Daniel Lichtblau of Wolfram Research.  (I confirmed that it still works in the current version (7.0) of Mathematica.)

---

Footnotes:

[1] What's really handy is that you can mix and match that with function definitions.  Like:

```
fib[0] = 1;
fib[1] = 1;
fib[n_] := fib[n-1] + fib[n-2]
```

You can then add memoization by changing that last line to

```
fib[n_] := fib[n] = fib[n-1] + fib[n-2]
```

which says to cache the answer for all subsequent calls.